# Unstable Transmission Rate in TCP by Packet Loss

Tags: networking, tcp

Is it true that TCP does not provide a stable transmission rate, because TCP always keep increasing the bandwidth until there is a packet loss?

Comment: That is a gross over-simplification. There is a whole lot more to it than that.

Comment: Quick brief question may warrant a quick brief answer! Vague specificity for sure!! Look at the `Data Transfer` section here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol for the `Flow control` point. I'd personally suggest a lot more reading about TCP and then see if you still have the question or add more to it.

Answer (score 0):

No.  TCP does provide a stable transmission rate (in conjunction with the rest of the stack.

If hops are bursty or saturated it is designed to drop packets to send a signal to slow down the transfer - a (very) small amount of packet loss in TCP is actually normal.